# How to convert a mac address to long in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, json, mac-address

My Javascript code:

```
    function singleCopySave()
    {   
        var sam1="00:A0:C9:14:C8:29";
        var mac=toLrad.split(":").map(Integer.parseInt(_,16)).foldLeft(0L) {case (acc,item) => acc*256+item};

        var JSONObject = {};
        JSONObject["toLrad"]=sam1;
        var jsonData=dojo.toJson(JSONObject);
        dojo.xhrPost({
               url :"/unified/singleCopy", 
               preventCache:true,
               handleAs: "text", 
               postData:jsonData,
               headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
               sync:true,   
               load: function(response, ioArgs)
                {
                retVal = response;
                },
               error: function(errorResponse, ioArgs)
                {

                }

               });
            }
```

My Java REST code looks like below:

```
@POST
@Path("/singleCopy")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String singleApCopy(sampleDTO dto,@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) {
    long toLradId = dto.getToLrad();
return "success";
```

> It is not hitting the REST url. There's a mistake in converting the string value to long. Could someone please help me out the syntax problem in converting to long? 
>       Or is there a way to convert the mac address in the DTO.java ?

Comment: a mac address is 6 x 2 hex digits ... you have 4 ... and you have a `v` - which isn't hex

Comment: @JaromandaX That is just a sample. I have the right MAC address passed.
I have changed it accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
var mac= parseInt(sam1.split(':').join(''), 16);

var JSONObject = {};
JSONObject["toLrad"]=mac;
```

you must send json property `toLrad` as long, it will able to convert in Java method